# Using OnNavigatedTo for two table - Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, datacontext

Evetything is fine with this code:

```
string selectedRowOrderId = "";
   if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedRowOrderId))
            {
                int selectedID = int.Parse(selectedRowOrderId);
                var query = from TblOrders order in orderDB.Orders
                            where order.OrderId == selectedID
                            select order;

                DataContext = new ObservableCollection<TblOrders>(query)[0];
            }
```

I am able to display order details on the page. But I would like to display Order Products (from TblProductsToOrder) on the same page as a list under the order details. I mean, DataContext has to have one more query from TblProductsToOrder like this:

```
DataContext = new ObservableCollection<TblProductsToOrder>(query2)[0];
```

Could you help me how to have these two in the DataContext an the same time?

Comment: can you explain better your needs?

Comment: i think you should give names to parts of your code like `headerPanel.DataContext=query.FirstOrDefault();` for the orders
`itemsPanel.DataContext=query2.ToList();` for the details

Comment: I have 3 Tables (TblOrders, TblProducts and TblProductsToOrders) And I have an OrderList. When tap one of them, I can have OrderDetailsPage. (OrderDate, Customer Name etc.) I would like to be able to add products as a list to this page. But in this case, My datacontext only has TblOrders values...

Comment: You could extend your Orders class to include a List of Products witch will be populated only when they are required.

Comment: Probably there are many better ways then what I am trying :) But my only problem is to put 2 query in DataContext and Bind XAML side using  this new DataContext.

Comment: there is another way witch is create a class that hold orderdetails and orderProducts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot change the model to include the reference between the Tables, you have another solution to your problem:

```
public class OrderDetailsAndProducts
{
    public TblOrders Order { get; set; }
    public TblProductsToOrder OrderProduct { get; set; }
}
```

in your assignment to DataContext you should be doing like this

```
OrderDetailsAndProducts orderDetails=
      new OrderDetailsAndProducts
      {
          Order = query.FirstOrDefault(),
          OrderProduct = query2.FirstOrDefault()
      };
DataContext = orderDetails;
```

From what i understand about your database schema you should have more Products in the Order if it is so the class to hold both should be more like this:

```
public class OrderDetailsAndProducts
{
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public List<TblProductsToOrder> OrderProducts { get; set; }
}
```

in your assignment to DataContext you should be doing like this

```
OrderDetailsAndProducts orderDetails=
      new OrderDetailsAndProducts
      {
          TblOrders = query.FirstOrDefault(),
          OrderProducts = query2.ToList()
      };
DataContext = orderDetails;
```